How to change launcher's Icon background?
I am trying to change my apps launcher icon background color but still is not changing. I have tried many methods but it failed.
your text`I ma using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1 package
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: false
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  background_color: "#FF5733"  # Set your desired background color
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FF5733"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/icon.png"


Steps to Update Launcher Icon Background

Verify Assets: Ensure the file assets/icon/icon.png exists and is correctly referenced in your pubspec.yaml:

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/icon/icon.png


Configure in pubspec.yaml:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: false
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FF5733"  # Background color
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/icon.png"


Run the Package:

If using pubspec.yaml or flutter_launcher_icons.yaml:



flutter pub get
dart run flutter_launcher_icons


If you name your configuration file something other than flutter_launcher_icons.yaml or pubspec.yaml you will need to specify the name of the file when running the package.

flutter pub get
dart run flutter_launcher_icons -f <your_config_file_name_here>


Clean and Rebuild the App:

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run


Important Notes:

⚠ Warning: flutter_icons has been deprecated. Use flutter_launcher_icons in your configuration files instead.



